# How to prevent race condition when creating a document on parse server?

Tags: mongodb, parse-platform, parse-server

A mobile app uses parse server as a backend with `mongoDB` as database.

For every user in the `User` collection there is a user profile in the `UserProfile` collection. A user profile has a pointer field as a reference to the `User` to which the user profile belongs.

The problem is that multiple user profiles are created for the same user during sign up.

That is because the sign-up process looks like this:

1. **Client:** user signs up
2. **Server:** creates user profile in `afterSave` of `User`
3. **Client:** after sign-up calls cloud code function `updateProfile` to update information in the user profile
4. **Server:** `updateProfile` looks for existing user profile or creates a new one if none exists

This causes a race condition: The server creates a user profile in step #2 and at the same time `updateProfile` creates a new user profile in step #4. The time difference in `createdAt` of these user profiles is milliseconds.

Now:

- If I leave out step #2, then even if step #4 gets calls multiple times immediately after each other, it can cause a race condition because `updateProfile` won't find a user profile until it's created. On the other hand every user needs to have a user profile associated with it, so creating it server side is the only way to ensure that.
- If I change step #4, to not create a new profile, then the information in the profile is not updated when the client calls the cloud code function `updateProfile` because the user profile from step #1 is not yet created.

What is the correct approach?

### Update:

- Unfortunately the user profile cannot be created on `beforeSave` of the `User` because it doesn't seem to have an `ID` yet. If that was possible then it would be ensured that a user profile is created *before* the client calls `updateProfile`.

Comment: Does the UserProfile have a pointer to User?  If so, you can make a unique index on that field.

Comment: I thought of that, it prevents multiple user profiles. However, step #4 will still fail because it won't find the user profile that hasn't been created by step #2 yet. I need something that ensures that the write operation in step #2 is done before the find/modify operation in step #4.

Comment: so why even bother doing #2?  why not count on #4 to do the work.  but you should make the unique index anyway.

Comment: Please show your code.  What you're trying to do is easily done without race conditions.  In a nutshell, (a) you can have your afterSave hook create *and update* the profile and skip step #4, or (b) skip step #2, and *after user creation is complete* call updateProfile (which will do a create first if there is none).  If one or both of those approaches is failing, then the code requires review.

Comment: @danh (a) `afterSave` hook for `User` class cannot *update* the user profile because the information to update is provided by the client in step #4, so step #4 cannot be skipped. (b) if step #2 is skipped, then the creation of a user profile is determined by the client. If a client is terminated after the user creation request and before the response (e.g. on slow network), then no user profile will be created. No code to review here, this is a conceptual question.

Comment: If no user profile is created and the functionality of this updateProfile method will update *or create* a profile, it sounds like you don't have any gaps? I don't think you actually have an issue.